# Loadrunner Parameters in JSON String

Tags: automated-tests, load-testing, loadrunner

I'm trying to use a parameter inside of a JSON string, and would like to use an inner parameter to replace an GUID. I've changed the default parameter start and end characters since curly braces are used in JSON.

I've tried to do something like this, where the json param contains my json which is similar to this below.

```
{"DashboardGUID":"<Dash_GUID>"}
```

```
request_json = lr_eval_string("<json>");
lr_save_string(request_json, "request_json_param");
```

I'm expecting the lr_eval_string to replace the  with the GUID that's in this parameter, what's the best why of replacing this ID in my JSON String?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking but I will put this here in case someone comes here in the future:

main.c

```
Action()
{
    lr_eval_json("Buffer/File=my_json.json", "JsonObject=MJO",LAST);
    lr_json_stringify("JsonObject=MJO","Format=compact", "OutputParam=newJsonBody",LAST);
    lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(lr_eval_string("{newJsonBody}")),"tmp");  

    web_reg_find("Text={mydate}",LAST);
    web_rest("POST",
        "URL=http://myServer.microfocus.com/url",
        "Method=POST",
        "EncType=raw",
        "Body={tmp}",
        HEADERS,
        "Name=Content-Type", "Value=application/json", ENDHEADER,
        LAST);

    return 0;
}
```

my_json.json

```
{
    "LastActionId": 0,
    "Updated": "{mydate}"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so instead of doing what I'm thinking above I ended up creating an array of char's with this `{"DashboardGUID":"<Dash_GUID>", someotherdata:"123"}` in 10 different positions within the array. I then randomly selected an element from this array and when doing the lr_eval_string the parameter was replaced.

Hopefully this makes sense those looking to do something similar.